# Zoom with Axis: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd3.event.transform')

Tags: d3.js

I have a heat map visualisation. Please find the link [here](https://observablehq.com/d/287af954b6aaf349).

I am trying to implement a zoomable heat map where the X axis was changed by scales’ domains via `transform.rescaleX`. The transformed scales are used to draw axes.

However, the `zoom` function does not apply on X axis and as I inspect in the console: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd3.event.transform)`

I can't get my head around on this issue.

Is anyone can help me to understand why it is not working?

Thank you for reading my questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.event` has been removed in version 6. Instead, the `event` is now the first argument in any callback function, with `d` the second argument.

From [the release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0):

> Remove d3.event; selection.on now passes events directly to listeners.